# Insert and Update

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I started with a table which looked something like this:

> Dog(ID, Gender,Name)

It was decided to create a new owner table.

> Owner(ID, Name)

Where the Owner-ID is a GUID data type.

and to update the Dog table to:

> Dog(ID, Gender, Name, OwnerID)

As the database was being used by multiple programs and not all programs could be updated at the same time the decision was taken not to enforce this new relation and so Null values were allowed for OwnerID, but any value in the dogs Owner ID must correspond to a value in the Owner table.

Now we've reached a point where all of the software creates dogs that have owners, but we wish to fix the entries where dogs do not have owners.

We wish to create an empty owner entry for each dog that currently does not have an owner.
We're not worried about two dogs having the same owner as this can be amended later if necessary.

What would be the most efficient way of achieving this?
Effectively I'm looking to

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Owner]
       ([ID],[Name])
 VALUES
       (newid(), 'n/a')
```

For each Dog where the dog's ownerID is null.

Then Update

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Dog]
   SET [Owner_ID] = NewIDFromAbove
```

Is there any single statement or similar neat way of doing this?
Would Merge be useful here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use output clause to fix this issue, E.g

```
declare @newIds table(id nvarchar(255));
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Owner]
       ([ID],[Name])
      output inserted.id into @newIds  
 VALUES
       (newid(), 'n/a')
```

Comment: Not possible with single statement but we can then use @newIds table in next statement i.e in Update Dog...